# Multiple commands to run using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, powershell

I am developing a tool on Visual Studio 2010 which has a button which executes a powershell program. But before this execution we need to change the path on cmd prompt.

```
cd Try & powershell C:\Users\Medha\Try\out.ps1
```

, this statement works fine on cmd prompt but in my VB code, both the commands are taken together and executed at once, which needs to be one by one.

I have tried this

```
 > Shell("cmd.exe /k" + "cd Try & powershell C:\Users\Medha\Try\out.ps1")
```

Please suggest changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `WorkingDirectory` property

```
Dim myProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
//if it's in system directory use Environment.SystemDirectory
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "your\working\directory"
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
myProcess.Start
```

Comment: this would change the directory too ?

Comment: by default, cmd prompt opens up with C:, that itself I change it to Try directory first and then execute the powershell code as the powershell program generates some files initially which is used later in that code itself. for that it is necessary to change the path first so that the file created in middle gets created in the Try directory and can be used further